# Is it OK to have two AMD GPIO Controller with different drivers?

Tags: drivers, bsod

when I access the Device Manager on my computer, I find there two "AMD GPIO Controller". When asking for driver info, one of them report its driver is from 02-04-2019 version 2.0.1.0 while the second says it is from 28-10-2019 and version 2.2.0.124.

Since both are kinda like the same stuff (both are GPIO Controllers from AMD), I find odd they would have two different driver versions. The most curious part, though, is that when I run one of those automatic driver update utilities such as Driver Boost, it only detects and updates the second driver (of course, when it considers outdated). In other words, it's like the first GPIO Controller is 'hidden' from such utilities. In one occasion, I downloaded the driver and tried to manually update using the "Update Driver" button in the Device Manager only to find out Windows wouldn't accept my replacement telling "it concluded the most recent version is already installed" - when, given the driver version of the second GPIO Controller, that seems mistaken.

So what is happening here? Why is that I simply can't update the driver of the first GPIO Controller both automatically as well as manually? Notice that I suffer from tons of BSODs (just in the last 30 minutes I got two and one of them didn't even produce a dump file!) and I wouldn't be surprised if this may be one of the reasons for them. I'm using W10 and AMD Ryzen 7 1800X processor.

Comment: Worth considering: They may be similar, but are they the same? If not the same they could very well use different (though confusingly identically named) driver packages.

Comment: A bit like a petrol car, which uses 'fuel', and a diesel car, which also uses 'fuel' (but not the same fuel!)

Comment: @Hennes well they do seem to be at least complementary! When I look upon their "Details" in Device Manager, they seem pretty similar only changing some location info. For instance, "identification" of them is ACPI\AMDI0030 and ACPI\AMDIF030. One is service amdgpio2 other amdgpio3. And many of the other parameters have identical values.

Comment: @Hennes It's also worth mentioning, but every other component in Device Manager which I found that had two or more identical names, their drivers were always the same version. The situation with this AMD GPIO Controller is the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems the correct answer is "yet, it is OK". It seems AMD works with two different kinds of GPIO Controllers and each uses its own driver, thus the difference in version. This was confirmed by me after accessing AMD's webpage and downloading an app to update my chipset drivers. In the options menu, two chipset drivers were shown and they had this version number difference. So it seems it's just how AMD works, or at least with my AM4 chipset.